# Gradle build error when trying to Generate Signed Apk

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

About 34hours ago I generated a signed apk but now, I've been unable to generate a signed Apk and I have no idea on how to fix this. Please Help

Here's my Output message

> Error:Note: there were 11 duplicate class definitions.
>         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0.
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project :app
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0.
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.pom'.
>   >     jcenter.bintray.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0.
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.0/lint-gradle-26.1.0.pom'.
>   >     dl.google.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 10s

Here's my build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp……"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 5
        versionName "5.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:$firebase_version"
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:$firebase_version"
    implementation 'io.github.yavski:fab-speed-dial:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.codemybrainsout.rating:ratingdialog:1.0.8'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Here's my build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'
    ext.support_version = '26.1.0'
    ext.firebase_version = '12.0.1'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 39):

It's a lintValidRelease issue.
You need an add lintOptions in Gradle file.

```
android {
..
     lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! that would work but what i did was that i connected to the internet when generating the signed Apk and by itself it did the magic

Comment: Adding `lintOptions` works, but it seems like a workaround. What is the root cause? I'm connected to the internet and it doesn't help.

Comment: I would also like to find root cause for this. suddenly my CircleCi started throwing me this error `Execution failed for task 'app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'app:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not find lint-checks.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/26.1.2/lint-checks-26.1.2.jar`

Comment: Disabling Firewall may helps you sometimes

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was due to the missing repositories in `allproject` part:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

allprojects {
    ...
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

after I added `google()` and `jcenter()` the project now is built successfully

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference for me, at least not in the build.gradle a level above the "app" directory.